# Does a high score in Math subject GRE helps in applying to a Finance PhD program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

Does a high score in Math subject GRE helps in applying to a Econ PhD program?

Say you got to the 90th percentile, so in a sense that shows your math is better than 90% of the math majors. In an Econ PhD program where math is heavily involved, I suppose this would make a difference?

(a side question to this, how can you highlight a good score in math subject GRE when normal applicants only takes the General GRE?)

Answer (score 2):

While a strong GRE score certainly won't hurt your chances of admission, I think that in general students place too much emphasis on test scores relative to their actual importance in the admissions process.

The only case where this will make a substantial difference is in an "edge" case—where you're on the borderline of being admitted or not and the small "bump" could cause a significant change in the outcome. (If you were a clear admit, the GRE score won't make a difference, and if your candidacy is otherwise weak, a strong GRE score won't rescue it.)

As for how to highlight it, I would just put that information in a "miscellaneous comments" section of the form, if it's available.

Comment: I'm talking about Math subject GRE viewed by a Finance department. I think you didn't address my concern directly

Comment: @manga_lovers: Actually, there's strategically no real difference here between the general and subject GREs. Acing a subject test is not really going to help you that much more, unless you're on a bubble.